# Redirect www.domain.com to sub.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect www.domain.com to sub.domain.com except when url is www.domain.com/something and in that case keep it that way. I couldn't find any solution on the google and anytime I try to implement this in my own, I get www.www.domain.com. Thanks in advance!

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. When I type domain.com it stays as it is, same about www.domain.com

Comment: I posted this after testing. Are you sure you have .htacess and mod_rewrite enabled? If yes then post your complete .htaccess in your question.